# I get an error while dockerizing my nodejs project

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, npm-install

I am trying to dockerize an application for a project. I'm using node.js as my server. In the process of dockerizing it throws this error:

```
cloud_project2-projectapp-1           | npm ERR! code ENOENT
cloud_project2-projectapp-1           | npm ERR! syscall open
cloud_project2-projectapp-1           | npm ERR! path /projectapp/package.json
cloud_project2-projectapp-1           | npm ERR! errno -2
cloud_project2-projectapp-1           | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/projectapp/package.json'
cloud_project2-projectapp-1           | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
cloud_project2-projectapp-1           | npm ERR! enoent
```

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```bash
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /projectapp
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
ENV PORT = 8080
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm","run","devStart"]
```

The dockerfile is exactly as I've seen in many videos and in the documentation. I believe the error is thrown in the RUN npm ci command and for some reason it cannot find the package.json file even though I copy it in the above command. I also searched for some answers and maybe it's a priviledges issue, but I'm new to linux and have a hard time understanding these.

I get a couple more errors with mysql and keyrock, but I'll debug these later.

```yaml
version: "3.9"

networks:
  idm_network:
    driver: bridge

#project images
services:
  projectapp:
     build:
       context: ./projectapp
     networks:
       - idm_network
     volumes:    
      - .:/projectapp   #for development phase only
     ports:
       - "8080:8080"  

  mysql:
      build:
        context:
          ./mysql
      networks:
        - idm_network
      volumes:
        - project-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=idm
        - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%


  keyrock:
    image: fiware/idm:latest  
    networks:
        - idm_network
    depends_on:
        - mysql
    environment:
        - IDM_DB_HOST=mysql


  mongo-orion:
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - project-mongo-orion-data:/data/db
    networks:
      - idm_network
    command: --nojournal

  orion:
    image: fiware/orion
    links:
     - mongo-orion
    networks:
      - idm_network
    command: -dbhost mongo-orion

  mongo-data:
    build:
      context: ./mongoData
    volumes:
      - project-mongo-data:/data/db
    networks:
      - idm_network

  data-storage-server:
    build:
      context: ./dataStorageServer
    volumes:   
      - .:/dataserver  #for development phase only
    depends_on:
      - mongo-data
    networks:
      - idm_network

  #pep-proxy-datastorage:
  #  image: fiware/pep-proxy:latest
  #  networks:
  #    - idm_network

  #pep-proxy-orion:
  #image: fiware/pep-proxy:latest
  #networks:
  #  - idm_network

#project volumes
volumes:
  project-mysql-data:
  project-mongo-orion-data:
  project-mongo-data:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the `volumes:` block under `projectapp`.

What this block does is replace your entire application in the image with content from the host system.  (Imagine installing a copy of Node normally, then separately checking out Node's source code and unpacking it over the installed Node you already have.)  There's no particular guarantee or check that the image and the host content "match".  Things like the `node_modules` tree that the image `npm install`s get hidden as well.

In your case, you're building the image out of a `./projectapp` subdirectory, but bind-mounting the current directory `.` over the image code.  That causes there to not be a `package.json` when you run the container, which produces the error you see.

I might make two more changes to this setup.  If you delete *all* of the `networks:` blocks in the file, Compose will create a network named `default` and attach all of the containers to it; this will work exactly the same way as the network you have now, but require less setup.  You can also use a shorthand `build: directoryname` which means the same as the `build: { context: directoryname }` you have now.  That, plus deleting the unnecessary `volumes:`, would get you down to

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  projectapp:
    build: ./projectapp
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"  

  ...

  mongo-data:
    build: ./mongoData
    volumes:  # keep volumes for persistent database data
      - project-mongo-data:/data/db

  data-storage-server:
    build: ./dataStorageServer
    depends_on:
      - mongo-data
```

The `orion` service also has the obsolete `links:` option and you can just delete that block as well (or change it to `depends_on:`); the name `mongo-orion` will still resolve using normal Docker networking.

Comment: Thank you that was it, but does nodemon work if I save changes in my local machine inside docker?

Comment: I'd recommend doing day-to-day development directly on the host system.  You can `docker-compose up --build` to recreate the containers with updated code once the unit tests pass on the host.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was I had this line:

```
volumes:    
      - .:/projectapp   #for development phase only
```

so that I don't have to restart docker every time I made a change, but it created a problem.